# Read SOAP XML by ASMX web servcie function

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services, soap, asmx

I wrote a simple web service (ASMX) function in VB:

```
Public Function processMessage(ByVal Messages as XMLElement) As String  
    Dim strS as string
    strS = Messages.outerXML
    Return strS
End Function
```

And test by sending the following request (attempt to read two messages):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:gps-hex-communicator">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <processMessage xmlns="urn:gps-hex-communicator">
            <Messages>
                <Message>
                    <DeviceID>11A</DeviceID>
                    <MessageID>1111B</MessageID>
                </Message>    
                <Message>
                    <DeviceID>22A</DeviceID>
                    <MessageID>2222B<MessageID>
                </Message>
            </Messages>
        </processMessage>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And get the following response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <processMessageResponse xmlns="urn:gps-hex-communicator">
            <processMessageResult><![CDATA[<Message xmlns="urn:gps-hex-communicator">
                <DeviceID>11A</DeviceID>
                <MessageID>1111B</MessageID>
                </Message>]]></processMessageResult>
            </processMessageResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The problem is that it stops after reading first message and second one never shows up.  How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a broken tag on the second message

```
<MessageID>2222B<MessageID>
```

should probably be

```
 <MessageID>2222B</MessageID>
```

Comment: Thanks point out the typing mistake.  I've got the solution now.  The <XmlAnyElementAttribute()> can be used to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody.  I got the answer now.  The XmlAnyElementAttribute helps to get everything in.  So the first line of asmx function should be:

```
Public Function processMessage(<XmlAnyElementAttribute()> ByVal Messages as XmlElement) As String
```